# Example of "reference loop" which can prevent "__del__()" from being called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(I'm using Python `3.6.5`)

I'm debugging a production problem which seems to be caused by `__del__` not being called. I added debug messages in both `__init_` and `__del__` and it turned out sometimes (when the product problem was hit) `__del__` is not called.

I Googled a lot and based on my understanding there are 2 cases where `__del__` may not be called:

1. `os._exit()`
2. Cyclic reference (or reference loop)

I'm quite sure we did not call `os._exit()` so I suspect the problem was most likely caused by some *reference loop* but I failed to figure out what a *reference loop* would look like. So could someone help give an example of *reference loop* which can prevent `__del__` from being called?

Comment: is it possible to show the piece of code causing the issue?

Comment: Daemon threads can also prevent `__del__` from executing, as can force-killing a program with `kill` or similar means.

Comment: Reference cycles became irrelevant to this staring in Python 3.4, so that's not it: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/

Comment: So, are you sure you aren't just keeping some reference around? Why do you *believe* `__del__` should be called?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's not a daemon so the app will exit after some time. i think `__del__` should be called. is my understanding wrong? could you give an example?

Comment: @TimPeters so that makes my question invalid. :(

Comment: @pynexj **why** do you think it should be called? Can you demonstrate your reasoning? We're only going to be able to speculate unless you elaborate.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's my understand of OO. all objects will be automatically destroyed when the app exits in a normal way (not by `os._exit()`).

Comment: i know (and have verified) a few scenarios where `__del__` is not called when the prog exits but that's with python 2.7.

Comment: @pynexj yes, but `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called if the object is still alive when the interpreter exists. This is in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok i just saw that. but i'd expect that's for very special scenarios which people cannot hit easily. any real (and simple) example?

Comment: Sure, I know it happens when you use a file-object and don't close it explicitly, something like `f = open('example.txt', 'w'); f.write('hi')`

Comment: But I am not particularly convinced that is the cause of your problems, I'm just saying, it is possible.

Comment: how can i know the `__del__` is not called? (actually i believe the `__del__` was called for this simple scenario.)

Comment: To know whether it was called, put code in it to do something out of Python's control - say, create a new file. The new file then shows up or it doesn't.

Comment: the file was created and text witten to it without a problem. sounds like i need to add some debug info in the file class' `__del__`.

Comment: @TimPeters just found an example where `__del__` is not called with python 3.4+. posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the [PEP 0442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/) (Python 3.4) mentioned in the comment did not work for all scenarios. Just found an example from [here](https://ideone.com/2UvmrW) (tested with Python **3.5.3**):

```
[STEP 101] # cat ref_loop.py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        print("now in __init__")
        self.foo = self

    def __del__(self):
        print("now in __del__")

foo = Foo()
exit()
[STEP 102] # python3 ref_loop.py
now in __init__
[STEP 103] # python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
[STEP 104] #
```

My another Python **3.6.5** can also reproduce it.

Note that if `exit()` is removed then `__del__()` will be called though I don't understand why.

Comment: `__del__` is run under 3.7.5 and 3.8.1 - at least on my box ;-)  I don't have older versions in the 3 series available.  As @juanpa.arrivillaga said, there's no guarantee `__del__` will run for objects present at exit - interpreter shutdown is extremely complicated.  It does tend to become more thorough over time, though.

Comment: BTW, for things that absolutely must be run at (a clean) shutdown, the `atexit` module's facilities have always been used. But what if you want to run a cleanup action in case of garbage collection, or shutdown, whichever comes first? There was no easy answer to that before 3.4 added `weakref.finalize()`. See the weakref docs for that, and don't miss the "Comparing finalizers with __del__() methods" section at the end.